# ¿Qué uso le damos a la etiqueta [background]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

Les pido opiniones respecto al uso de [background](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background).

Actualmente tiene el siguiente extracto, mal definido, con un doble sentido:

> Se puede usar en dos contextos, el primero como proceso en segundo
>   plano. También se puede usar como fondo (a nivel gráfico).

¿Qué les parece?

- ¿Es una meta-etiqueta y deberíamos editarla para eliminarla de esas​ preguntas?
- ¿Separarla en dos (o más) diferentes?
- ¿Definir un extracto para sólo uno de estos casos y eliminarla de la preguntas en las que se use para el otro significado?
- ¿Traducirla?

Por el bajo volumen de preguntas en las que se usó, esto no representa un problema que no podamos solucionar editando, pero creo que es uno de los casos que es bueno identificar a tiempo antes de que sean inmanejables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Propongo que para desambiguar la etiqueta se cree una nueva sólo para lo relacionado con el contexto de los procesos en segundo plano:

[procesos-en-segundo-plano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procesos-en-segundo-plano) como etiqueta maestra

Opino que **no** deberíamos crear una etiqueta que se refiera o haga alución a *background* como fondos de imágenes o cosas parecidas

Comment: ¿Pero entonces se debería crear una etiqueta para referirnos a fondos de imágenes?

Comment: Me parece una buena opción, veamos qué opina el resto.

Comment: Opino que **no**, me parece innecesaria pues es algo que se puede describir fácilmente en el cuerpo de la pregunta

Comment: @Mariano, editada, ahora que lo pienso, si suena innecesario el sinónimo

Answer (score 6):

## Voto por quemarla.

No sirve como etiqueta, se presta a confusion. Un usuario la usara para procesos en segundo plano y otro la usara para cambiar el fondo de un `<div>`.

Tendriamos que hacer trabajo manual de eliminar la etiqueta de las preguntas mal etiquetadas.

Comment: Entiendo lo de *no usarla*... Pero me parece que quemarla es un poco drástico para una etiqueta que sólo está en 16 preguntas, que podemos eliminarla manualmente, y que no creo que esté causando "daño".

Comment: Quemarla, impedir que se use nunca jamas. Nunca va ser util esta etiqueta (salvo que surja un software llamado `background` :), ¿para que dejara? la volverian a usar una y otra vez... dando trabajo manual y nuevas discusiones, etc. Resuelve bien, una sola vez.

Comment: Se ha eliminado la etiqueta en cuestión de todas las preguntas que la tenía al día de hoy, 17. Coincido con Mariano que quemarla es algo que debe reservarse para casos de recurrencia del mal uso.

Answer (score 0):

> Se puede usar en dos contextos, el primero como proceso en segundo
>   plano. También se puede usar como fondo (a nivel gráfico).

Para el primer contexto, concuerdo con la respuesta de [ArtEze](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2102/78).

Para el segundo contexto creo que no tiene uso. Si la pregunta trata sobre algo gráfico, la pregunta debe proveer etiquetas como CSS, HTML, etc. - solo es un ejemplo :)

En caso de que la etiqueta no aplique para el segundo contexto, concuerdo con eliminarla (editarla manualmente y sacarla de esas publicaciones). Las preguntas usualmente tienen mas de una etiqueta que ayudan a definir a qué background se refiere.

Comment: Para terminar de entender, con "eliminarla", ¿te estás refiriendo a editarla manualmente y sacarla de esas publicaciones?

Comment: Si. Quitarla de las preguntas y eliminar su uso (a menos que se cambie por un nombre como "css-background").

Comment: entonces sería [lo mismo que respondió @Jorius](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2061/127)?

Comment: @Mariano, si tienes razón. respuesta votada a favor (así como las respuestas de Emanuel y ArtEze).

Answer (score -1):

Estoy de acuerdo con la respuesta de @Jorius en parte. Por un lado, veo bien lo siguiente:

> [procesos-en-segundo-plano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procesos-en-segundo-plano) (etiqueta maestra) - [background](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background)

Pero pienso que además habría que crear la etiqueta [fondo-gráfico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fondo-gr%c3%a1fico).